# Flutter update image in storage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using `ImagePickerWeb` and upload an images in `Storage`. For display this images I am using url. If user change image, how to update in storage? The first need delete previous image and upload again?

```
Future uploadImg() async {
var timekey = DateTime.now();
fb.StorageReference storageReference =
    fb.storage().ref('imgProduct/${timekey.toString()}.jpg');
fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTask = await storageReference
    .put(_image1, fb.UploadMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpg'))
    .future;

var imageUrl = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();

url = imageUrl.toString();
print('Image Url' + url);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the database with the new photo url and then delete the old image from firebase storage.

Comment: `fb.Storage` storage =` fb.Storage.getInstance();` getinstance give me 1 positional argument(s) expected. jsObject. Can you explain me?

Comment: do you have any user collection in the firestore database? or are you recording the user data anywhere?